# Simplification: $(3x^3y^2-1)y'+3x^2y^3=1$ to $y'=-\frac{3x^2y^3−1}{3x^3y^2−1}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having a hard time understanding simplifying equations. Please could someone show me how you get from:

$$(3x^3y^2-1)y'+3x^2y^3=1$$

to:

$$y'=-\frac{3x^2y^3−1}{3x^3y^2−1}$$

when I work on this I get:

$$y'=\frac{1-3x^2y^3}{3x^3y^2−1}$$

Comment: Note that $1 - 3x^2y^3 = -(3x^2 y^3 - 1)$ since minus times minus is plus.

Comment: so my answer was correct?

Comment: Yes the last equation is the same as the next to last equation.

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to showing $$ab+c=d\iff b=-\frac{c-d}{a}$$ for $a\neq 0$.

We have

$$\begin{align}
ab+c=d &\iff ab=d-c\quad(\text{subtract }c) \\
&\iff ab=-(c-d)\quad(\text{factor out }-1) \\
&\iff b=-\frac{c-d}{a}\quad(\text{dividing by }a\text{ assuming } a\neq 0).
\end{align}$$